# Write a Script to delete files which are 7 days old on the server

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am uploading a file on the Linux server and I want these files to be deleted after a week.
Basically I want to write a script which will run everyday and delete the files which are 7 days old. What else I can do here? And also if anybody can guide me to write the script. Thanks!

Comment: man cron, man bash - if manpage is not enough, google

Comment: You'll want to take a look at `man find` and its command line options and use this as the basis of your command.

Comment: AND this gets asked at least 1x per month here on S.O., so try searching here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

run `crontab -e`, go to the last line and append a line like this:

```
0 9 * * *  find /absolute/path/ -type f -name \*.ext -ctime +7 -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

where `.ext` is the file extension. This will run the command every day at 9am. Look at the comments in the same file for more examples.

But please read the `find`, `xargs` and `rm` manpages first.

```
man find 
man xargs
man rm
man crontab
```

I hope you're aware that in a week you can find out that you've got ZERO files (if no new files are copied). **DON'T USE THIS FOR CLEANING UP BACKUPS.**